# Enable Orientation in UIWebview when Evaluating Javascript

Tags: javascript, ipad, uiwebview, uiinterfaceorientation

When i start to evaluate the javascript like when the user select the text, highlight the selected text. For those kind of situations i am not able to continue with the  device orientation in iPad and stops the orientation and it is not active until the javascript completely executed.

Is there any way to handle the evaluation of javascript in uiwebview without affecting the uiwebview orientation.

Answer (score 0):

sure.
when you start your javascript you can set a boolean var and set a var with the current orientation of your UIViewController (both vars in your UIViewController instance),
then in your UIViewController you must implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

it's the method that tell the iPhone if it can rotate your app when users rotate the device.

so, when your javascript starts:

// BOOL stopRotation; // declare it in yourViewController.h
stopRotation = TRUE;
// UIInterfaceOrientation* currentOrientationFrozen;  // declare it in yourViewController.h
currentOrientationFrozen = self.interfaceOrientation;

and:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        if (stopRotation){
             if (interfaceOrientation == currentOrientationFrozen) {
                 return YES;
             } else {
                 return NO;
             }
        } 
        return YES;

    }
```

then, when your javaScript stops, restore your BOOL and currentOrientationFrozen:

```
stopRotation = FALSE;
currentOrientationFrozen = nil;
```